# Google TV remote app can't discover device

Tags: television, samsung-smart-tv

I am building Google TV remote app (official sample from Google).
But it's can't find any google tv device.

I found Samsung official remote app works fine.
Does Samsung change the service name or broadcast port?

I am using Google nexus one and Samsung Smart TV.

Answer (score 0):

Google TV is not the Samsung Smart TV. It's completely different platform.

Thats why Google TV remote app doesn't work with your Samsung Smart TV.